# My Wake-on-LAN only works if I manually press sleep mode

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have followed instructions online and setup everything for Wake-on-LAN. If I just press sleep in my Windows 7, I can use an app to wake it up. But if I let it inactive for 20 minutes which is the time I set to auto sleep, then I cannot wake my computer up. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You might have missed some settings somewhere. You may have to experiment a little with your BIOS & LAN power management settings seems. You may want to attach screenshots of LAN Advanced Properties, power management etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Wake on LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), called to WOL is a feature from some Networking Devices who grant you the option to send a Power-On Signal using a software to a NIC or Port.

When your system turns into a **Sleep Mode** or your NIC goes to **Power Safe Mode**, the **Magic Packet** have some problems but they can be solved.

In the first case Sleep Mode the answer is simple:

> **[I had a Technical inaccuracy but ive Updated]**

You can enable Windows WoL Feature to Wake Up the system in Sleep Mode with a Magic Packet Checking this Box:

[image]

In the second case:

**The Interface is Shutdown** -  So cant reach the destiny.

**How to disable Power Safe Feature from an Network Adapter.**

- Start Button > Run > Tipe `mmc devmgmt.msc` and press
  <kbd>Intro</kbd>
- Expand Network Adapters select the desired adapter Right click and
  press Properties.
- Select Power Management Tab.
- Uncheck *Allow the Computer to turn off this device to Save Power*.
- Press OK.

[image]

Comment: May I know how to fix it?

Comment: @Annie answer improved.

Comment: You are saying I should just set the computer to never sleep!?

Comment: when my computer goes to sleep mode after 10 minutes, it would be in sleep mode, all power down looking, keyboard and desktop tower no light.

Comment: @Annie I had a Technical inaccuracy but ive Updated. ive attached the new updated infomation.

Comment: I followed this: http://windows7-issues.blogspot.hk/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html which is very different than what you mentioned above, and kind of opposite.